# The error message "TypeError: unsupported addressable value (argument="target", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.11.1)" when run locally

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, hardhat

**I created a script that fetches the WETH interface and send some test ETH**

getWeth.js

```
const { getNamedAccounts, ethers } = require("hardhat")

const AMOUNT = ethers.parseEther("0.1")

async function getWeth() {
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const iWeth = await ethers.getContractAt(
        "IWeth",
        "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
        deployer,
    )
    const txResponse = await iWeth.deposit({
        value: AMOUNT,
    })
    await txResponse.wait(1)
    const wethBalance = await iWeth.balanceOf(deployer)
    console.log(`Got ${wethBalance.toString()} WETH`)
}

module.exports = { getWeth, AMOUNT }
```

aaveBorrow.js

```
const { getWeth } = require("../scripts/getWeth")

async function main() {
    await getWeth()
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

When I run the scripts using `yarn hardhat run scripts/aaveBorrow.js`

I am returned with and error

```
TypeError: unsupported addressable value (argument="target", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.11.1)
    at makeError (/home/raaghavmanivel/hardhat-defi/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:687:21)
    at assert (/home/raaghavmanivel/hardhat-defi/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:715:25)
    at assertArgument (/home/raaghavmanivel/hardhat-defi/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:727:5)
    at resolveAddress (/home/raaghavmanivel/hardhat-defi/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/address/checks.ts:122:19)
    at /home/raaghavmanivel/hardhat-defi/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:172:60
    at ParamType.#walkAsync (/home/raaghavmanivel/hardhat-defi/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/abi/fragments.ts:779:24)
    at ParamType.walkAsync (/home/raaghavmanivel/hardhat-defi/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/abi/fragments.ts:797:24)
    at /home/raaghavmanivel/hardhat-defi/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:170:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveArgs (/home/raaghavmanivel/hardhat-defi/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:169:37) {
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'target',
  value: undefined,
  shortMessage: 'unsupported addressable value'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `signer` instead of `deployer` in the `getContractAt()` function, because the transaction corresponding to the `deposit()` function needs to be signed.

The `signer` can be created from the `deployer` like this:

```
const signer = await ethers.getSigner(deployer);
```

Hence, the revised code for **getWeth.js** file would be:

```
const { getNamedAccounts, ethers } = require("hardhat")

const AMOUNT = ethers.parseEther("0.1")

async function getWeth() {
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()

    const signer = await ethers.getSigner(deployer);

    const iWeth = await ethers.getContractAt(
        "IWeth",
        "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
        signer
    );
    const txResponse = await iWeth.deposit({
        value: AMOUNT,
    })
    await txResponse.wait(1)
    const wethBalance = await iWeth.balanceOf(deployer)
    console.log(`Got ${wethBalance.toString()} WETH`)
}

module.exports = { getWeth, AMOUNT }
```

Comment: Thank you,That worked.But I have one more question,when I tried commenting out line by line on the earlier program, the getContrractAt and transfer function passed and I got an error only at the balanceOf function. Also,what exactly is the difference between deployer and signer?

Comment: @RaaghavManivel, if you hover over `getContractAt` function, then you can see the params that it's expecting as well as its return type **(** i.e., `(property) HardhatEthersHelpers.getContractAt: (nameOrAbi: string | any[], address: string | Addressable, signer?: Signer | undefined) => Promise<Contract>` **)**.  So, it can't work with passing the `deployer` (i.e., an address/wallet address), it needs the `signer` (i.e., an object that can sign the transactions, and it's being created by the combination of **RPC** of the network and the **private key** corresponding to the `deployer` address).